# __bridge_transfer and CFBridgingRelease has different result in ARC code

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

`CFBridgingRelease` should be the same as `__bridge_transfer` in ARC, but in my code they are have different results.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        CFMutableArrayRef cfObject = CFArrayCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, NULL);
        printf("retain count = %ld\n", CFGetRetainCount(cfObject));
        //id obj = (__bridge_transfer id)(cfObject);
        id obj = CFBridgingRelease(cfObject);
        printf("retain count after the cast = %ld\n", CFGetRetainCount(cfObject));
        NSLog(@"class=%@", obj);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

If use **`__bridge_transfer`**, the result is as follow:

```
retain count = 1
retain count after the cast = 1
2018-04-27 11:02:28.945866+0800 P01[2344:1638938] class=()
```

If use **`CFBridgingRelease`**, the result is as follow:

```
retain count = 1
retain count after the cast = 2
2018-04-27 11:03:30.795628+0800 P01[2363:1658495] class=()
```

**The different results only happened in the Mac Command Line Tool.** 
If I put the code in the iOS App, the result is the same. Confused!!!

Comment: After the bridge, the object is now under ARC memory management. The CFTypeRef is to all intents and purposes dead. You should be looking at `obj`, not at `cfObject`, and you should be looking at its `retainCount`, not `CFRetainCount`. (But of course you can't do that, because this is ARC. In fact, you should _never_ be looking at any object's retain count in either fashion. Just do correct memory management and move on. If you do it right, you will neither leak nor dangle, and that is all that matters.)

Comment: @matt: Doesn't `CFBridgingRelease` more or less just  return `(__bridge_transfer id)X`?

Comment: Yes but it returns it on the left side of the equal sign, as `obj`. What happens to the CFTypeRef after the transfer is meaningless. I’m just repeating myself....

Comment: @matt, thanks for your explanation.